# I have migrated the my files from existing server to new server?but testing , session is working

Tags: codeigniter

I migrated my current application to new server, after entering the details in the URL it's not going forward. I have changed in  base file, helper `utility_helper` files like

```
define('BASE_URL','http://lotusvalue.com/leadmanagement/');
```

to new server

```
define('BASE_URL','http://lotusvalueproperty.com/leadmanagement/');
```

after this also, I am unable to login with my username and password, for testing I have created my sessions code in URL, but that shows working,

```
http://lotusvalueproperty.com/leadmanagement/sessions.php
```

I want to know what are the other possible things I want to check in my code to execute this application.
my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: enable rewrite mode on your server if you use ubuntu server then check [here](http://www.iasptk.com/enable-apache-mod_rewrite-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: I am using godaddy shared server,linux server, acess the url http://lotusvalueproperty.com/leadmanagement/  username:admin@lotusvalue.com pass:test, it shows 404 error but existing server it is working fine, try giving new idea  and possible solutions

Comment: have you check rewrite mode enable or not? if not then contact to godaddy support team they guide you

Comment: How to check you check rewrite mode enable or not? i have cpanel can i check now itself,

Comment: please do not share email / password here some one miss use that and there is an index.php  issue only not worry about that

Comment: ok,how to solve this, since three days i am breaking my head, that only have you seen this are u sure?, File not found (404 error)
If you think what you're looking for should be here, please contact the site owner.

Comment: create one phpinfo file then check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187865/discussion-between-pratik-lochawala-and-kaviya).

Comment: I created phpinfo file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing in user & database name, routes in config file. Also changing base_url in config file to your new url.

Comment: Yes I done that according to my new hosting ,and db username and password

Comment: no errors, I am getting now ,i am checking the script, but existing one, it's login fine, and i have not changed all code. but new server, After entering the details in the URL its not going forward.  <form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="loginform" method="post" role="form" action="http://lotusvalueproperty.com/leadmanagement/login" autocomplete="off">

Comment: if i give forgot password also , no action is coming,just i have changed the server.and created the db with username and password.URL its not going forward.

Comment: How to identity  my scripting is working well or not ?

Comment: shall i have to change rewrite rule

Comment: have you check your server has enable rewrite_mode ?